# How to post a file to server using Python that mimics the behavior of this R code?

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm able to succesfully POST some csv data to an external server using the `httr` package in R using a post request like so:

```
request <- POST(url, body = upload_file('my_table.csv'), verbose())
```

The detail provided by the `verbose()` option above tells me that the post request headers look like this:

```
-> User-Agent: libcurl/7.68.0 r-curl/4.3.1 httr/1.4.2
-> Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip, br
-> Accept: application/json, text/xml, application/xml, */*
-> Content-Type: text/csv
-> Content-Length: 77
->
```

What I'm trying to do is emulate this code with the Python requests module (because the rest of the package is in Python), and I'm using the following code:

```
response = requests.post(url, files = {'file': open('my_table.csv','rb')})
```

However, I'm getting a `error,Error: File type not supported` error from the server when I do so. When I look at the details of my POST request in Python, I see the following headers:

```
{'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.25.1', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Content-Length': '226', 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=b8f99a72145547743d035be5d9c1e983'}
```

What is the cleanest way for me to upload and post this CSV data such that the server might accept it?

Comment: In your R script, point URL to your  django app to capture what is sent and how they are sent

Comment: Sorry, I do not have a django app. I don't control this server I'm posting to if that's what you are assuming (if not, please correct).

Comment: Maybe the server expects the content-type to be set? Try `response = requests.post(url, files = {'file': ('my_table.csv', open('my_table.csv', 'rb'), 'text/csv')})`. It's hard to say when we have no idea what the server actually expects.

Comment: Thanks @MrFlick. I did try that and received the same response. While I understand that we might not know much about the server, I was hoping we'd at least be able to mimic the working R code, but maybe it's not as simple as I thought it might be.

Comment: That is why if R will do POST of your django app using a test view,  you will get the request header and body so you will know what to do

Comment: @mkalioby, as I said above, I do not have a django app, so I'm uncertain of how to proceed with your suggestion.

Comment: How about using the body directly? `response = requests.post(url, data = open('my_table.csv', 'rb'))` or maybe `response = requests.post(url, data = open('my_table.csv', 'rb'), headers={"Content-Type":"text/csv"})`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @MrFlick. Still no dice though...Same message.

Comment: Try posting both requests (form R and python) to a site like https://httpreq.com/ so you can see exactly what's being sent to the server and can compare them to find the differences.

Comment: My mistake sorry